# simple parity bit scheme

Tags: python, parity

I am trying to make a simple paritybit method in PyCharm, and I've written this code:

```
import bitarray as ba       # Library with bit strings

data = ba.bitarray(endian = 'little')       # String for data
data.frombytes('Secret message!'.encode())  # String for encoded EDC bits

def parity(bitarray):
    print("Original:\t\t\t{}".format(bitarray))
    #even = True                                        # Two protocols agree on either even or odd
    pbit = '0'                                          # Initiate parity bit as 0
    count = bitarray.count('1')                         # Count the number of ones
    print("Counted {} 1's in bitarray".format(count))
    if (count % 2) != 0:
        pbit = '1'                                      # If the bit array have an odd number of 1's we add parity bit 1 to make the number of 1's even
    print("Parity bit is {}".format(pbit))
    bitarray.append(pbit)
    print("Parity bitarray: \t{}".format(bitarray))
    return bitarray

parity(data)
```

And I get this output:

```
Original:        bitarray('110010101010011011000110010011101010011000101110000001001011011010100110110011101100111010000110111001101010011010000100')
Counted 58 1's in bitarray
Parity bit is 0
Parity bitarray: bitarray('1100101010100110110001100100111010100110001011100000010010110110101001101100111011001110100001101110011010100110100001001')
```

As you can see, the number of 1's is even, and the parity bit is 0, but my code has added a 1 at the end of the bitarray istead of a 0. I have tried to fix the problem, but I haven't managed to find a solution.

Comment: Still figuring what is the core issue, but the first ```if``` is redundant and ```even``` is never used

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Initially I get `'str' object has no attribute 'append'` so your sample code is not complete, but after making `data` a list it works, and a `0` gets printed as 'parity' and then appended. It also works correctly after changing any `0` to a `1` (or reverse) in the data.

Comment: I forgot to include the type of object I use as input. I have edited the sample code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the assignment of `'0'` and/or `'1'` to the parity bit `pbit`.

It seems that these strings, are both interpreted as binary ones. If you instead use the integer values `0` and `1` for `pbit` your code works:

```
def parity(bitarray):
    print("Original:\t\t\t{}".format(bitarray))
    pbit = 0 # Updated line
    count = bitarray.count('1')
    print("Counted {} 1's in bitarray".format(count))
    if (count % 2) != 0:
        pbit = 1 # Updated line
    print("Parity bit is {}".format(pbit))
    bitarray.append(pbit)
    print("Parity bitarray: \t{}".format(bitarray))
    return bitarray
```

This may be a bug in the `bitarray` module as it seems that strings seem to work in other places, such as in the `.count()` method, but I don't know enough about `bitarray` to say for certain.

Also, especially given that the `pbit` needs to be an integer, it would be easier to just assign it once, using the expression `pbit = count % 2` directly, i.e.:

```
def parity(bitarray):
    count = bitarray.count('1')
    pbit = count % 2
    bitarray.append(pbit)
    return bitarray
```